# Issue in Google Map APi KEY

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I am new android developer..I am making a location based reminder app, but map is not showing.

Here is the error.
Please tell me how to get API key and where to put...

```
-1943/com.app.locationreminder E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
04-22 10:02:57.530 1121-1943/com.app.locationreminder E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
04-22 10:02:57.535 1121-1943/com.app.locationreminder E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                 Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                 Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                 API Key: AIzaSyAv3T4PkWMNcHl2KOvmZ4z9o9xCcg6oO9Y
                 Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 0D:A3:D8:83:15:59:D7:61:D4:0D:28:62:3E:C1:48:07:24:81:7B:E0;com.app.locationreminder`
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#add_the_api_key_to_your_application) from google to use GMap API v2. Hope this will help you